# Spark. Java. PostgreSQL. How can I update record if it’s key exists

Tags: java, postgresql, apache-spark

I need to update or delete and insert new one record if it exists in PostgreSQL.
My table has unique key by few fields. And if new record in dafaFrame has the same value of these fields as record in PostgreSQL I want to delete old one and insert new one.
I didn’t found any possible ways to do it by Spark